# How can i error handle the spotify command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
async def spotify(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):

    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
        pass
    if user.activities:
        for activity in user.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, Spotify)== True:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f"{user.name}'s Spotify",
                    description="Listening to {}".format(activity.title),
                    color=activity.colour)
                duration = str(activity.duration)
                finalduration = duration[3:7]
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=activity.album_cover_url)
                embed.add_field(name="Artist", value=activity.artist)
                embed.add_field(name="Album", value=activity.album)
                embed.add_field(name="Song Duration", value=finalduration)
                embed.set_footer(text="Song started at {}".format(activity.created_at.strftime("%H:%M.%p")))
                embed.url = (f"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/{activity.track_id}")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

this is my spotify command and although it works fine I cant figure out how to error handle it.

For example, if the user is not listening to Spotify I want to make it send a message like "You are not listening to Spotify"

**Any help is appreciated** :)

Comment: Have you tried to use an `else` statement at the end of your code?

Comment: i have yeah still nothing

Comment: any other ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `await ctx.send("You are not listening to Spotify ")` at the end of your command, and add a `return` statement at the end of your `if instance(activity, Spotify) == True` statement. It will exit once it finds what the user is listening and sends the embeded message, and otherwise it will keep going to the end and send `You are not listening to spotify`

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def spotify(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
        pass
    if user.activities:
        for activity in user.activities:
            if str(activity).lower() == "spotify":
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f"{user.name}'s Spotify",
                    description="Listening to {}".format(activity.title),
                    color=activity.colour)
                duration = str(activity.duration)
                finalduration = duration[3:7]
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=activity.album_cover_url)
                embed.add_field(name="Artist", value=activity.artist)
                embed.add_field(name="Album", value=activity.album)
                embed.add_field(name="Song Duration", value=finalduration)
                embed.set_footer(text="Song started at {}".format(activity.created_at.strftime("%H:%M.%p")))
                embed.url = (f"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/{activity.track_id}")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                return
    await ctx.send("User is not doing anything")
    return
```

Note: I modify the `if isinstance(activity, Spotify)== True:` in my code because it wasn't working for me, but you can keep it since you said it was working for you.

Comment: First of all ty.Also my bad its supposed to be `if isinstance(activity, Spotify):`

Answer (score 1):

First of all welcome to stack overflow.Maybe try something like

```
for activity in user.activities:
     if activity!= spotify :
         await ctx.send("You are not listening to Spotify ")
         break
```

Comment: i will try it. ty

Comment: it does not work for some reason it just does not read that Spotify as an activity anymore even though I have it listening to music.